# C# multiple constructors with base and subclasses

Tags: c#

I have following super class and subclasses.

I am getting compile time error :

```
1) Error    3   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'DomainObjectModel.ObjectModel.PocoProjectData' is less accessible than method 'DomainObjectModel.ObjectModel.Project.Project(DomainObjectModel.ObjectModel.PocoProjectData)'    C:\Workspace\POC\Final\oCPDSService\oCPDSService\DomainObjectModel\ObjectModel\Project.cs   19  12  DomainObjectModel

2)Error 4   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'DomainObjectModel.ObjectModel.PocoProjectData' is less accessible than method 'DomainObjectModel.ObjectModel.Project.ProjectCapacity.ProjectCapacity(DomainObjectModel.ObjectModel.PocoProjectData)'    C:\Workspace\POC\Final\oCPDSService\oCPDSService\DomainObjectModel\ObjectModel\Project.cs   102 14  DomainObjectModel

3) Error    5   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'DomainObjectModel.ObjectModel.PocoProjectData' is less accessible than method 'DomainObjectModel.ObjectModel.Project.ProjectCIP.ProjectCIP(DomainObjectModel.ObjectModel.PocoProjectData)'  C:\Workspace\POC\Final\oCPDSService\oCPDSService\DomainObjectModel\ObjectModel\Project.cs   154 14  DomainObjectModel



    namespace DomainObjectModel.ObjectModel
    {  
    public class Project
    {
     public Project()
     {
      SchedulePhases = new HashSet<SchedulePhase>();
     }

     public Project(PocoProjectData pocoProjectData)
     {
      SchedulePhases = new HashSet<SchedulePhase>();

      this.AssetId = pocoProjectData.AssetID;
      this.CapitalCategoryId = pocoProjectData.CapitalCategoryID;
      this.ProgramCategoryId = pocoProjectData.ProgramCategoryID;
      this.StatusId = 1;
      this.DSFId = pocoProjectData.DsfNumber;
      this.IsRollover = "N";
      this.IsDeferred = "N";
      this.IsApproved = "N";
      this.FundingSourceId = 12;
      this.IsLongTermLease = "Y";     

     }

    [Key]
    public decimal ProjectId { get; set; }

    public decimal AssetId { get; set; }

    public decimal CapitalCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SchedulePhase> SchedulePhases { get; set; }

    protected bool success = false;

    public virtual bool CalculateSchedule(int projectType)
    {
      return success;
    }

    public class ProjectCapacity : Project
    {
      public ProjectCapacity(PocoProjectData pocoProjectData)
        : base(pocoProjectData)
      {

      }

      public override bool CalculateSchedule()
      {          
        return success;
      }
    }

    public class ProjectCIP : Project
    {
      public ProjectCIP(PocoProjectData pocoProjectData)
        : base(pocoProjectData)
      {

      }

      public override bool CalculateSchedule(int projectType)
      {        
        return success;
      }
    }

}
```

Also how to call subclass CalculateSchedule() from base class Project in order to get Project.SchedulePhases collection?

Thanks,

Comment: The error messages you have given us explain what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that `PocoProjectData` is less accessible then `Project`. 
Project is marked as public, so PocoProjectData needs to be at least public as well. Check that.

Comment: But how to call subclass method from super class? In my case it is CalculateSchedule()

Comment: ask another question for this